# Template variables with PHPMailer 5.1

Tags: php, templates, variables, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send out an email based on a template file included this way:

`$body = file_get_contents('petition_email.html');`

The template contents a variable $name that I would like to replace with a value from my php script.

As of now, the script outputs $name as simple text along with the rest of the message.

How do I make sure that my template text is being parsed for variables and $name is being replaced with the actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
$body = str_replace('$name', $name);
```

Right after that file_get_contents call, if you are loading an HTML file. Make sure you assign your variable before you try to replace it though (assign it in the same script).

Comment: Thank you! What worked is `$body = str_replace('$name', $name, $body);`

Comment: Oops forgot the third argument. Good job on figuring it out.